# Using Euler's formula to evaluate this series

Tags: complex-numbers, power-series

I have the following exercise:

> Let $a$ be a complex constant such that $|a|<1$. Use Euler's formula to prove that
>   $$1 + a\cos \theta + a^2 \cos 2\theta + a^3 \cos 3 \theta + ... = \frac{1-a\cos \theta}{1-2a\cos \theta + a^2}$$

I initially tried to define:
$$z := ae^{i\theta}$$
And so the series would become:
$$\operatorname{Re}(z^0) +\operatorname{Re}(z^1) + \operatorname{Re}(z^2) + \operatorname{Re}(z^3) + ... $$
And then i tried to search for a closed formula for $\operatorname{Re}(z^n)$, but the ones i found seemed to be pretty [dirty and messy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263805/real-and-imaginary-parts-of-x-iyn)(i would be doing a infinite sum of partial sums) . So i concluded that the approach of a series of real parts wouldn't be the best approach to the problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the series $\sum z^n$, find its sum, and *then* take the real part.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.